# Bracha on seeing indirect light from lightning?

Tags: halacha, blessing, see-sight-vision-blind, weather

As [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1935/when-to-make-a-bracha-on-lightning) mentions, one should say the bracha if the sky lights up, even if one does not see the bolt.

What if one is facing away from the window when lightning strikes and the light fills the room? Does this count as seeing lightning?

Comment: Did you take a look at the source quoted in the answer on that question to see how broadly it might apply?

Comment: I don't currently have access to it. A link would be helpful.

Comment: Why isn't this a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: As alluded to by others, the preexisting question already asks about "a bracha on a room illuminated from lightning from behind a curtain", which is similar enough to this that I'm seconding the motion to close.

Comment: @msh210 might it make sense to remove the bit about the curtain in that question?

Comment: @SethJ the curtain bit seems similar enough to the rest, and no one considered removing it until now. Moreover, the answer there *seems* to address the curtain part also (though fleshing out that answer would clarify whether it does). All in all, I think keep it. What do others think?

Comment: @msh210 the reason I think it might make sense to remove it is because, without the curtain, this would be identical to that - the light comes into the room and you don't see the source; with the curtain, the curtain (like the clouds) are the reason you don't see the source, of the light. Just illuminating the room, might not be good enough. You might need some object to have gotten in the way. If nothing got in the way, then if you weren't looking maybe we say that, since you could have seen it it's as if you had your eyes closed and missed it altogether.

Comment: @msh210, I'm not saying that's the Halachah; I'm just saying that it creates enough of a difference in the cases for me to wonder if the law is different, and therefore enough for the questions to be asked separately.

Comment: @SethJ, by that logic we should keep the curtain part there and reopen this as a separate question.

Comment: @msh210 You could. That's why I asked.

Comment: @SethJ, thanks for correcting me, especially, and also for doing it so nicely.

Comment: @msh210 You're welcome(?). I was just putting the question out there, though, really not trying to nitpick or correct anyone or anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Shu"t Tzitz Eliezer* ([vol 12 *siman* 21](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14511&st=&pgnum=67&hilite=)) writes:

> אבל גבי ברכת הברק מצינו היפוכו של דבר, דבשום מקום בתלמודין וברמב"ם וטור ושו"ע לא כתוב על זה בלשון הרואה, ומכיון שכן ברור הדבר שלא בעינן בזה שיראה גוף הברק בשמים, וצריך לברך גם **כשרואה על הארץ** קרני האור של הברק

It would appear from this that even if he only saw it in his room he would say the *beracha*, and not only if he saw it while looking outside.