# May one say the bracha on seeing lightning, meteors, or comets if viewed through binoculars or a telescope?

Tags: blessing, technology

O.C. 227:1 indicates saying בא"ה אמ"ה עושה מעשה בראשית on seeing זיקין (Mechaber describes this as a meteor; Mishnah Berurah surmises that this may be a comet.) The same blessing is suggested for seeing lightning.

Obviously (no pun, intended, here) this means if one sees these with a naked eye. What if one sees any of these via binoculars or through a telescope? Would he make the bracha, then?

I read [this article](https://astrorav.com/2015/12/28/blessings-on-comets/). The author cites an article written by Rabbi J. David Bleich in Contemporary Halachic Problems v.1 (p.213-5) who discusses this question. I clicked the link which displays Google books, but most of the answer is not displayed. The rest of the authors article says that he asked his own (anonymous) rav who told him, you would make a bracha using binoculars; questionable if with a telescope.

That's all I was able to find. As the rav was not listed, and the author of the article is unknown, I'm wondering if there is a more reliable definitive answer to this question.

Comment: would this be the same for someone who wears glasses, or hears thunder by cupping his hand to his ear?

Comment: @rosends I made some edits since you posted your comment. It may assist in answering your question or forming an opinion in some way.

Comment: @rosends a refractive telescope would be just like glasses and a reflective telescope would be like seeing it in a mirror. There isn't much else to say about this

Comment: relevant comment I found connected to seeing something on television: Yechave Daat 2:28 compares it to saying birkat halevana upon seeing the moon in the mirror, which we do not do based on the gemara in rosh hashana 24b and birkei yosef Choshen Mishpat 35:11. see also Sh"t Bitzel Hachochma 2:19, Beer Moshe 2:9 [ http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Brachot_on_Sights#cite_ref-19 ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bracha on seeing indirect light from lightning?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29611/bracha-on-seeing-indirect-light-from-lightning)

Comment: If I recall correctly, I believe both the Brisker Rav in regard to thread counts in fabric and Reb Moshe Feinstein in connection with the microscopically visible insects in milk products address this idea. In general, we act according to what we perceive with our unassisted senses.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Generally, yes. However, I think that in deciding many of these issues, the underlying question deals with a limit to how much a device alters that perception. E.g., the consensus is that cochlear implant wearers fulfill the mitzvah of hearing shofar, because the implant does not significantly alter the original sound. Read the linked article. It suggest that use of binoculars most likely is permitted, based on similar thinking. The problem seems to be more related to telescope use.

Comment: @Ploni not exactly a dupe. In that question, you are not using a device. It is closely related, though.

Comment: @DanF The teaching from the Brisker seemed to indicate that. The person asking the question could not see the threads in question. The Brisker could. If I understand cochlear implants, the person still hears without it, just poorly. So for a low magnification binocular, it isn't giving you something you don't have already. It's simply improving clarity & acuity. Telescopes allow you to see things you actually can't perceive naturally.

Comment: @YaacovDeane In brief, cochlear implants "process" the sound. However, it is similar to what a microphone does; i.e., it is considered close to the original sound and there is insignificant delay. There is a pamphlet produced by a rav in Baltimore who has studied with all types of technical & haalchic aspects regarding the deaf and hearing-impaired. If you're interested in reading about it, inform me - I'll get you the name of the pamphlet. It's not online AFAIK.

Comment: @DanF I'm always interested. I've read so many responsa arguing back and forth about whether this type of sound is an echo or an echo of an echo, and in many cases it seems to me that what drives people to be more stringent in this area is what the origin of the sounds are from. If it is something they want to be stringent over, it becomes a simple echo. If not, then it becomes an echo of an echo and the stringency can be disregarded. A lot of it seems to me to be very arbitrary and political.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Start with http://www.jdcc.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=766:our-jewish-hearing-friends-in-our-deaf-circle&catid=287:feature-article&Itemid=283. There is a brief description of the issue. This is the person that wrote the pamphlets. You can prob. contact him, directly, to mail it to you.