# Should one say a bracha when observing extraterrestrial lightning?

Tags: blessing, outer-space

Follow up to [my related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84658/5275) on whether one can make a bracha on lightning observed through a telescope.

Assuming that one can do this, should he make a bracha when observing lightning occurring on [Jupiter, Saturn or Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning#Extraterrestrial).

Comment: I guess it is not like eating bacteria is permitted because it can not be seen with the naked eye, becouse the lightning can be seen with the naked eye if the person is there

Comment: @hazoriz Please explain your analogy. I don't understand it.